# Setting up Adam optimizer in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, neural-network

I'm reading a paper where the authors has following setting.
$Learning Rate= 1^{-3}, momentum=0.9, \beta_2=0.01, \lambda=1, \epsilon=10^{-4}$

However, tensorflow has following setting for Adam.

```
tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07, amsgrad=False,
                          name='Adam', **kwargs)
```

My question is, how do I set $momentum$ and $\lambda$

Comment: momnet depends on beta_1, `m = beta_1 * m_pre + (1 - beta_1) * g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look in this in  the documentation:

```
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1)
var1 = tf.Variable(10.0)
loss = lambda: (var1 ** 2)/2.0       # d(loss)/d(var1) == var1
step_count = opt.minimize(loss, [var1]).numpy()
# The first step is `-learning_rate*sign(grad)`
var1.numpy()
```

Beta1 and beta 2 : are the momentum decay; please check this:https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam

Comment: What is lambda (for adam) that the authors are talking about?

Comment: Well, I am not sure, I was checking previous answer on stack overflow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57613079/compile-error-on-keras-sequential-model-with-custom-loss-function , may this could help you to get somewhere